# PHP ganon dom parser get next element when match is found

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, ganon

I am parsing and html dom string from ganon dom parser and want to get the next element plain text when a match is found on previous element e.g my html is like

```
<tr class="last even">
   <th class="label">SKU</th>
   <td class="data last">some sku here i want to get </td> 
</tr>
```

I have used the following code for now

```
$html = str_get_dom('html string here');
foreach ($html('th.label') as $elem){
                if($elem->getPlainText()=='SKU'){ //this is right
                    echo $elem->getSibling(1)->getPlainText(); // this is not working
                }
            }
```

If the th with class lable and innerhtml **SKU** is found then get the innerhtml from next sibling that is **SKU value**

Please help to sort this out.

Comment: `$html()`? variable functions? execuse me while I go claw out my eyes.

Comment: @MarcB https://code.google.com/p/ganon/wiki/AccesElements

Comment: yes, I know. my comment still holds. variable functions are evil, just like variable variables.

Comment: @MarcB Any idea for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a bug in "ganon" of the html - if you take your example of html:

```
$html = '<table>
                <tr class="last even">
                   <th class="label">SKU</th>
                   <td class="data last">some sku here i want to get </td> 
                </tr>
            </table>';

   $html = str_get_dom($html);
```

for some reason because of the new line in the html "ganon" thinks that the next element is a text element and only then there is the desire td - so you have to do this:

```
   foreach ($html('th.label') as $elem){
        if($elem->getPlainText()=='SKU'){ 
            //elem -> text node -> td node
            echo($elem->getSibling(1)->getSibling(1)->getPlainText()); 
        }
    }
```

If you organize your html like this (without new line):

```
$html = '<table>
                <tr class="last even">
                   <th class="label">SKU</th><td class="data last">some sku here i want to get </td> 
                </tr>
            </table>';
```

Then your original code will work `$elem->getSibling(1)->getPlainText()`

Maybe consider using the [php simple html dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) class - it's much more intuitive, using full oop methods, jquery dom parser like and don't uses this awful var-function method :):

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');

    $html = '<table>
                <tr class="last even">
                   <th class="label">SKU</th>
                   <td class="data last">some sku here i want to get </td> 
                </tr>
            </table>';

   $dom = str_get_html($html); 


   foreach($dom->find('th.label') as $el){
       if($el->plaintext == 'SKU'){  
            echo($el->next_sibling()->plaintext);
       }
   }
```

Comment: Previously i have used simple html dom parser but its very that i cant load the my full page html dom and were sending timeout.. very slow tired from this.

Comment: thanks a lot for $elem->getSibling(1)->getSibling(1)->getPlainText() it worked.

Comment: Any idea for getting javascript content using ganon i have my js like <script>someplugin.({images.push('some url here i want to read ')})</script> 
Thanks

Comment: take the script tag as a dom and get it's innertext - in simple dom it's like that for example: `$dom->find('script',0)->innertext `